# Core Data Filter Abstract Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I have this core data setup:

```
Issue 
(IssueField)IssueFields (to many, Abstracted)

IssueField
(String)type

TextField : IssueField
(String)text

DateField : IssueField
(Date)date
```

So entity Issue have a to many relation with IssueField
IssueField is Abstracted and have two children TextField, DateField

I want to run a predicate to find Issue contain any DateField at a date

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Issue"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any IssueFields.type = %@ and any IssueField.date = %@", @"DateType", today];
```

but I got this error:
 reason: 'keypath IssueField.date not found in entity '

I understand this is due to query try to find date on a TextField, but how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Your `IssueField` entity doesn't have the `date` property as it is `DateField` that inherits from `IssueField` not the other way around. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve so I can't really comment on a way to solve it. Why do you need a separate `TextField` and `DateField` entities? (as opposed to having them as `IssueField` properties?

Comment: there a separated component that config how many fields an issue can have for a project, this structure allow issue field to be extended in future to accommodate new data type.  so Issue have a list of IssueField, IssueField can be a text field or a date field, there is also value list field, document field, number field and etc.

Comment: Hmmm why not just have an `IssueField` entity that has a property `type` and a property `value`. Type will store the field type and and value will store the field value. Also this might help https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data entities are not objects.  Abstraction like this should not be used.

First, when you use abstract entities like this, and/or entity inheritance, all of your child objects will exist in the same table in SQLite.  This can and does cause poor performance.

Second, Core Data is not a database.  Database type normalization also does not apply.  In your case, you should combine the two entities, TextField and DateField into one entity.  It will be a fairly simple logic check to determine which situation you are dealing with.